# как правильно передать в атрибут value код php?

Tags: php

Как правильно передать в атрибут value код php? Я знаю, что код неверно вложила. Если не передавать в переменную код работает

```
 $content = " <input type='text' value='<?php if(isset($_POST['my_text'])){ echo $_POST['my_text'];} ?>' name='my_text'/>
```

Переменная $content позже записывается в файл `fwrite($f, $content . PHP_EOL);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать короткий синтаксис и `<?php` не нужно, вы и так PHP код пишите:

```
$content = "<input type='text' value='" . isset($_POST['my_text']) ? $_POST['my_text'] : '' . "' name='my_text'/>";
```

Comment: Из моей практики, при конкатенации условие лучше поместить в скобки, а иначе вылазит ошибка.
$content = "<input type='text' value='" . (isset($_POST['my_text']) ? $_POST['my_text'] : '') . "' name='my_text'/>";

Comment: У меня отработало без ошибок, я бы вообще через sprintf делал на самом деле.